# Multidimensional array: printing addition table in C

Tags: c

```
int main(){
int row=0,col=0;
printf("Enter number of rows of the table\n");
scanf("%d",&row);
printf("Enter number of columns of the table\n");
scanf("%d",&col);
printTable(row,col);
}

void printTable(int row,int col){
int i =0,j=0,k=1,L=1,num=0;
printf("row: %d, col: %d\n",row,col);   
int table[row][col];
for (i;i<row;i++){
    for (j;j<col;j++){
        table[i][j] = i+j;
        printf("%d ", table[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Trying to print an addition table using multidimensional array, my output looks like this:

row: 4, col: 4

0 1 2 3

But I'm supposed to get

0 1 2 3

1 2 3 4

2 3 4 5

3 4 5 6

Please help me get right output. thanks

Comment: You get no compilation errors for `int table[row][col]`???

Comment: As of C99 there is a thing call `variable length arrays` which allow you to specify the size of an array at run time without using malloc. `int table[row][col]` is valid on a modern compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (j;j<col;j++){
```

You aren't resetting `j` to zero before the second and subsequent passes. Change that to

```
for (j=0;j<col;j++){
```

You might want to change the other for-loop (on `i`) as well. Generally, unless you have a Very Good Reason for not doing so, you should always be initializing the loop variable before the first pass; that's why that first clause of the `for` syntax exists, after all.

By the way, if you *didn't* want to initialize the loop variable, you could have written this as `for (;j<col;j++){` -- as you wrote it, the `j` is conceptually just retrieving that variable's value and throwing it away, and the `for` permits just leaving the initization, test, and/or update clauses empty if you don't need them. In fact, `for(;;) {` means the same thing as `while(true) {`, loop forever... and some people like to set up a macro,

```
#define EVER ;;
```

just so they can write the cutesy `for(EVER) {`

Answer (score 1):

If you want output like

0 1 2 3

1 2 3 4

2 3 4 5

3 4 5 6

Then following code prints the same outpit

```
for (i=0;i<row;i++){
for (j=0;j<col;j++){
    table[i][j] = i+j;
    printf("%d ", table[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}
```